# Does Latin only require on "mea"/"my" when English Requires two?

Tags: classical-latin

I just heard the motto "Patria gloria mea" in a movie. It was translated as "my country, my honor".
MY questions: Does Latin only require one "mea"/"my" when English Requires two?
Doesn't Patria mean fatherland rather than country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point of that translation was that *patria* is "my country", so it includes the other "my".
More literally, *patria* is "fatherland", and it would make sense to say *patria mea* as well.
Different people have different fatherlands, so for the same emphasis in Latin you would indeed want to have two copies of "mea".

If the motto is simply *patria gloria mea*, it sounds like "fatherland is my glory"; leaving out *est* is common in such settings.
If you want to say something closer to the English, I would prefer *patria mea, gloria mea*, although that could well be also read with an additional *est* — which hopefully doesn't matter all that much.